# Formatting a rounded number to x decimals when setting width for div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I divide a div into 2 part: left_contain and right_contain.
When the page is loaded, I use the statements below to calculate the width for those divs:

```
$('left_contain').css("width", detailLeftPanelWidth.toFixed(3));
$('.right_contain').css("width", detailRightPanelWidth.toFixed(3));
```

detailLeftPanelWidth and detailRightPanelWidth are values which rounded number to 3 decimals.

However, on FF browser, these values sometimes were rounded number to 2 decimals. The max-width is 1558px. After inspecting on FF, the width of left_contain is 374.625px (formatting a rounded number to 3 decimals) and the width of right_contain is 1183.38px (formatting a rounded number to 2 decimals, it should be 1183.375).
The sum of them is 1588.005px greater than max-width(1558px) 0.005px. So it
breaks my UI. 
[image]

I have no idea why FF browser automatically rounds number to 2 decimals as above.

Please help me solve this issue.

Regards,
Ken

Comment: I have also come across this issue before.  FF, Chrome and IE all look at the code in a different way.  What you can try do do is, set your math in a variable, and then pass that variable into the function.  That might solve the issue.